# Instanciar o objeto de um Map apenas quando necessário baseado em um regex

Tags: java, design-pattern, reflexão

Eu tenho uma `Factory` que instancia o `PARSER` responsavel para extrair as informações de um determinado formato de fatura. Para determinar o formato da fatura eu uso regex. Eu dou um loop em cada regex adicionado ao `Map` e verifico se o regex é encontrado dentro do texto dessa fatura, se for encontrado, então instancia o `PARSER` responsavel pela extração dos dados dessa fatura.

Pra isso, eu criei um `Map` de Class e String, onde String é o regex. Foi necessário utilizar Class pois não posso instanciar esse `PARSER` antes de saber se realmente é ele mesmo que vai ser o `PARSER` responsavel pois existem algumas lógicas no construtor de cada `PARSER`.

```
public class InvoiceParserFactory
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InvoiceParserFactory.class);

    private static Map<Class<? extends InvoiceParser>, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        map.put(xxx_PARSER.class, "regex_xxx");
        map.put(yyy_PARSER.class, "regex_yyy");
        map.put(zzz_PARSER.class, "regex_zzz");
        //...
    }

    public static InvoiceParser getParser(InvoicePdfReader reader)
    {
        String invoiceText = reader.getText();

        for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends InvoiceParser>, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Class<?> clazz = entry.getKey();
            String regex = entry.getValue();

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(invoiceText);

            if (m.find()) {
                try {
                    Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
                    return (InvoiceParser) constructor.newInstance(invoiceText);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Can't instantiate parser.", e);
                }
            }
        }

        throw new InvoiceException("Can't find parser.");
    }
}
```

**Dúvida**

Essa é a melhor prática para essa finalidade? Particularmente eu achei uma gambiarra. Alguma sugestão para melhorar/refatorar o código? Talvez utilizando features do Java 8?

**Problema**

No futuro, vou precisar além do regex, realizar alguma outra condição, então teria que refatorar completamente esse Factory para suportar que além de um regex, seja possível usar outras lógicas para instanciar o `PARSER` correto ou algo similar a isso. Qual a melhor prática nesse caso?

Comment: Particularmente não achei uma gambiarra não. Claro que ela tem limitações e não é o código mais bonito que já vimos, mas acredito que você deva pensar nestas limitações quando elas realmente te incomodarem (como no caso que citou). Vamos aguardar para ver se alguém propõe uma ideia melhor. Por enquanto vou pensando aqui em uma alternativa.

Answer (score 2):

Eu não acho gambiarra, embora tenha minha opinião pessoal quanto ao uso de reflection em produção (que deve ser moderado, o que no seu caso eu acho que é). *Mas esta é só minha opinião. Vamos ao código:*

Há uma limitação clara no código, que é o fato de todos os parsers serem obrigados a ter um construtor que recebe uma `String` (pois você está usando `clazz.getConstructor(String.class)`). Se você tomar este cuidado, não haverá problema.

Se no futuro você tiver outras lógicas além da regex para construir o parser, eu sugiro que você crie uma ou mais classes que encapsulem esta lógica:

```
public class LogicaCriacaoParser {
    public boolean condicoesSatisfeitas() {
        // retorna "true" se todas as condições para criar o parser são satisfeitas
        // pode ser a regex, e o que mais você precisar
    }
}
```

Neste caso o seu map teria instâncias de `LogicaCriacaoParser` (ou de subclasses dela, se preferir):

```
private static Map<Class<? extends InvoiceParser>, LogicaCriacaoParser> map = new HashMap<>();

static {
    map.put(xxx_PARSER.class, new LogicaCriacaoParser());
    map.put(yyy_PARSER.class, new Subclasse1LogicaCriacaoParser());
    map.put(zzz_PARSER.class, new Subclasse2LogicaCriacaoParser());
    //...
}
```

Assim, em cada subclasse de `LogicaCriacaoParser` você poderia implementar sua lógica específica para criar cada parser (dentro do método `condicoesSatisfeitas()`), podendo ser somente regex, ou regex + o critério que você precisar.

O ponto positivo é que você pode criar a lógica que quiser dentro desta classes (e de suas subclasses), e seu modelo não fica preso a uma lógica única, como por exemplo regex.

Para usar, seria algo do tipo:

```
LogicaCriacaoParser logica = entry.getValue();

if (logica.condicoesSatisfeitas()) {
    // cria o parser
}
```

---

### Alternativa (sem o map, nem reflection)

Na verdade você nem precisaria ter o map, e também é possível eliminar o uso de reflection.

A própria classe `LogicaCriacaoParser` poderia ter um método que retorna o parser específico, caso a condição seja satisfeita. Se preferir, pode deixar a classe abstrata e deixar que cada subclasse cuide do seu caso particular:

```
public abstract class LogicaCriacaoParser {
    // retorna "true" se todas as condições para criar o parser são satisfeitas
    // pode ser a regex, e o que mais você precisar
    protected abstract boolean condicoesSatisfeitas();

    // possui a lógica para criar o parser
    protected abstract InvoiceParser criarParser();

    // cria o parser se as condições forem satisfeitas
    public InvoiceParser getParser() {
        if (condicoesSatisfeitas()) {
             return criarParser();
        }
        // retorna null se as condições não forem satisfeitas
        return null;
    }
}
```

Repare que somente o método `getParser()` é público, pois é o único que as outras classes precisam conhecer.
Com isso, você precisa ter subclasses que sabem criar um parser específico:

```
// logica para criar XXX_Parser
public class LogicaCriacaoXXX_Parser extends LogicaCriacaoParser {
    protected boolean condicoesSatisfeitas() {
        // verifica as regras para criar o XXX_Parser (regex, etc)
    }

    protected InvoiceParser criarParser() {
        // retorna o XXX_Parser (usando new ao invés de reflection)
    }
}
```

Assim, você cria uma subclasse para cada parser diferente (yyy, zzz, etc), cada um implementando sua lógica específica.

Então, você teria apenas uma lista com todas as lógicas de criação de parser:

```
List<LogicaCriacaoParser> logicas = new ArrayList<>();
logicas.add(new LogicaCriacaoXXX_Parser());
logicas.add(new LogicaCriacaoYYY_Parser());
// etc.
```

E para criar um parser, você faz um loop nesta lista, até achar algum parser que satisfaz as condições:

```
for (LogicaCriacaoParser logica : logicas) {
    InvoiceParser parser = logica.getParser();
    if (parser != null) {
        return parser;
    }
}

// se não encontrar nenhum, lança o InvoiceException
```

Claro que há algumas melhorias, como alterar os construtores de cada classe de lógica para receber parâmetros, os próprios métodos para verificar as condições e criar o parser também podem receber parâmetros (que poderiam ser usados na construção do parser, por exemplo), etc.

Mas pelo menos você não está usando reflection (que pelo jeito você não se sentiu confortável usando, e eu te entendo), e você não fica dependente de cada subclasse de parser ter um construtor específico que recebe uma `String` (já que cada subclasse de lógica pode criar o parser usando `new`).